# Django: How to find which user has most posts on a certain 'sub'/forum?

Tags: python, django

I'm building a django app where I have a basic PostComment model below:

```
class PostComment(models.Model):
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=False)
    commenttag = models.ForeignKey('SubInfo') 
    postcommentdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    postcommentowner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.comment
```

and I would like to know which users have posted the most OPs on each 'sub'/forum to display a leaderboard of sorts for most active/contributing users. I'm a bit lost on how exactly to begin this. I know it involves going through each PostComment from a filter query for the `SubInfo` name and tallying up which `User` is attached to each comment and ordering the users by most tallies, but how do I do this in a non-memory intensive/fast way? Also, this code has to theoretically run every time a `PostComment` is made to see if the rankings change at all, correct? Can anyone tell me how to approach this with an example? Very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering for your user & forum should be fairly straightforward. For example;

```
sub_info = SubInfo.objects.get(name='whatever')
user_comments = PostComment.objects.filter(postcommentowner=request.user, commenttag=sub_info)
```

To get an idea of the number of objects, like to count a number of posts, you could then simply call `user_comments.count()` to get the number of comments in that query. Check the docs on [`count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#count)

If you've got database calls happening often, look to add a model manager to cache those results and when a particular user makes a comment effecting that cached result, invalidate the cache for that user.

Something like this might be quite helpful to you; [Simple Django queryset tips](http://phalt.co/simple-django-queryset-tips/)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've gotten that far, but for example, if a particular forum has hundreds of different users posting how should I parse through the posts to see which users have submitted the most posts? Does django have a function that counts how many times a certain property appears in a queryset? For example, I can take every single post from a particular sub by PostComment.objects.filter(commenttag=sub_info) but then how do I find the single user that has created the most objects in that entire queryset?

Comment: You can simply call `count()` on a given query. I'll update my answer.